# How to convert a model from torch to pytorch or caffe or any other model?

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'm trying to convert this t7 model to pytorch or to caffe or to caffe2 or to any other model..
this is what I get when converting to pytorch with the code from:
https://github.com/clcarwin/convert_torch_to_pytorch

has anyone had this error or know what to do with it?

```
roy@roy-Lenovo:~/convert_torch_to_pytorch$ python convert_torch.py -m model_a.t7 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "convert_torch.py", line 314, in <module>
        torch_to_pytorch(args.model,args.output)
      File "convert_torch.py", line 262, in torch_to_pytorch
        slist = lua_recursive_source(lnn.Sequential().add(model))
      File "/home/roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/legacy/nn/Sequential.py", line 15, in add
        self.output = module.output
      File "/home/roy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/utils/serialization/read_lua_file.py", line 99, in __getattr__
        return self._obj.get(k)
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Add a link to your model so others can check what's going on. This repository seems to be unmaintained for around 1 year, which is quite a long time when it comes to machine learning.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke here is the model link: 
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1T13xwXTLzxEHN_RF0i_0cvsetxX8H5vs